fail2ban | fail2ban-regex matches directly, but not in filter
Trying to get fail2ban up and working the way I'd like on an AlmaLinux 9 box. I'm really puzzled by something I hope someone can help me solve. Say want to ban an ip on all ports if fail2ban finds the following sort of string in /var/log/secure: "Failed password for invalid user ButtFacedDog from 111.222.333.444 port 666 ssh2"
So, a generic fail2ban regex starting point might be:
^.*Failed password for invalid user .* from <HOST> port \d+ ssh2$

If I try
 fail2ban-regex /var/log/secure '^.*Failed password for invalid user .* from <HOST> port \d+ ssh2$' --print-all-matched

works perfectly. Finds all the matches, and prints them out nicely formatted.
But...if I try to embed the regex in a filter (in filter.d) that I'll call invalid_user containing the following:
 [Definition]
 failregex =  ^.*Failed password for invalid user .* from <HOST> port \d+ ssh2$
 ignoreregex =

seems to fail miserably (which is perhaps why fail2ban doesn't seem to be baning the ip addresses I think it should be, based on what is in /var/log/secure). If I run
 fail2ban-regex /var/log/secure /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/invalid_user.conf

it returns...garbage (aka I have no idea what it is printing out, or why -- where are all the ip addresses? The first attempt explicitly passing the regex to fail2ban-regex printed all of them out).
For example,
 Results
 =======

 Failregex: 58402 total
 |-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
 |    1) [58402] ^.*Failed password for invalid user .* from <HOST> port \d+ ssh2$
 `-

 Ignoreregex: 0 total

 Date template hits:
 |- [# of hits] date format
 |  [278861] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
 `-

Is there any simple explanation for why the difference? More to the point (perhaps), how can I get it working? It seems as if the <HOST> argument is being interpreted differently in the two approaches.
Thanks in advance. Pointers to the obvious mistake(s) I must be making most appreciated.
